# Loop through an ArrayList to find missing values and create a dummy object

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a list which stores a object named GoldNetValue containing date and gold rate.There will be a difference of 10 minutes between the two records in the list and, in some cases no data will be available during the particular time interval.

Sample values as below

```
{GoldNetValue[2018-03-02 13:20 ,87], GoldNetValue[2018-03-02 13:30 ,86.4],GoldNetValue[2018-03-02 13:40 ,85.6]],GoldNetValue[2018-03-02 13:50 ,85.8]],GoldNetValue[2018-03-02 14:10 ,86.1]],GoldNetValue[2018-03-02 14:30 ,86.8]]
```

i need to loop through the list and create a new GoldNetValue object with missing date field and noDataAvailable flg enabled,then insert it back into the list. The difference is always 10 minutes.

```
int diffMins = 10;
Date tempDate = new Date();
for(int i= 0; i < goldNetList.size(); i++)
{
    GoldNetValue goldValue = (GoldNetValue) goldNetList.get(i);

    if(goldValue.getDate() != null && goldValue.getGoldRate() != null)
    {   
        tempDate = goldValue.getDate();
    }

    if() // logic yet to be implemented
}
```

lets say from 13:30 to 13:50 pm , there is only one record available , i need to create an object with date as 13:40 and noDataFlag enabled and store it back to the list.

i am a newbie just started to learn coding.

How can i populate through the list and create objects with flag enabled with these type of value combinations?

Thank you for your time

Comment: "*`GoldNetValue goldValue = (GoldNetValue)goldNetList.get(i);`*" - Why do you have to cast here? This suggests that something with your `goldNetList` is wrong, maybe a raw type? --- "*`List<GoldNetValue> goldNetList = {GoldNetValue[2018-03-02 13:20 ,87], GoldNetValue[2018-03-02 13:30 ,86.4],GoldNetValue[2018-03-02 13:40 ,85.6]],GoldNetValue[2018-03-02 13:50 ,85.8]],GoldNetValue[2018-03-02 14:10 ,86.1]],GoldNetValue[2018-03-02 14:30 ,86.8]]
`*" - I do not know what that is, but it is not Java.

Comment: Sorry editied my question .

Comment: @heath3n Note that alternating calls to next and previous will return the same element repeatedly.So in this case, I am getting the same value for both prevDate and curDate while iterating through the list.

Comment: StackOverflow is not supposed to be a code writing service. Although you have written some code, you are not showing any code that tries to actually solve the problem. Have a try and let us know when you get stuck, in a new question or an edit to this question.